# Parsing string to AST

Tags: parsing, haskell, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

Stuck trying to parse a string into an Abstract Syntax Tree

This is the grammar that im using, in BNF

```
<Block> ::= <Expr>;
<Expr> ::= <Number> | <App>
<App> ::= (<Expr>, <Expr>) <Func>
<Func> ::= + | - | * | \
<Number> ::= <Digit> | <Digit><Number>
<Digit> ::= 0 | 1 | .... | 9
```

I have to use this:

```
data Ast = Number Integer | Func String | App Ast [Ast] | Block [Ast]
```

I wrote a tokenize method (that perhaps is not completely finished, but gives the right idea)

```
tokenize :: String -> [String]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize xs @ (x : xs')
    | x `elem` t = [x] : tokenize xs'
    | isDigit x = [y | y <- takeWhile isDigit xs] : (tokenize (dropWhile isDigit xs))
    | otherwise = tokenize xs'
        where t = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', ';']
```

I'm stuck on the parseApp function. It's not obvious to me how I could use pattern matching, and I don't see any other way to do it (with my very limited haskell experience)

```
parse :: String -> Ast
parse xs = parseBlock (tokenize xs)

parseBlock :: [String] -> (Ast, [String]) 
parseBlock xss = let (a, b) = parseExpr (init xss) in (Block [a], b)

parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast, [String]) 
parseExpr xss @ (xs : xss')
    | all isDigit xs = (Number (read xs :: Integer), xss')
    | otherwise = parseApp xss

parseApp :: [String] -> (Ast, [String])
parseApp xss = -- ...
```

If the input string is

```
"((10, 2)- , (0, 2)-)+;"
```

it should tokenize to

```
["(", "(", "10", ",", "2", ")", "-", ",", "(", "0", ",", "2", ")", "-", ")", "+", ";"]
```

and that would become

```
(Block [ App (Name "+") [App (Name "-") [Number 10, Number 2], App (Name "-") [Number 0, Number 2]]], [])
```

It's an assignment so I can't change the types and so on. I'm supposed to assume that the given input has correct syntax. I have read similiar threads here, but the answers seem to assume a higher level of understanding

Comment: Here's a hint: when translating your grammar, bare tokens convert to pattern matches, and nonterminals convert to function calls.

Comment: You check `isDigit` inside the parser *and* the tokenizer. The need for this arises because your representation of a sequence of tokens is not sufficient - it should be `[Token]` where `Token` is your own type, e.g. `data Token = Number Natural | OParen | CParen | Semicolon...` etc. It would also help you to write a `Parser` abstraction instead of inlining parsing code everywhere. Also note your tokenize function is simply `filter (not . all isSpace) . groupBy (\a b -> all isDigit [a,b])` - try rewriting the parsing functions using HOFs in the same way - it will be much easier to reason about.

Comment: Ok so im supposed to traverse the list , string by string, and do the appropriate function calls. No trickery with extracting the last element and so forth? I think im supposed to be able to solve it with the given data type, even if its not optimal from a haskell pro pov (We're noobs and the subject is more about languages/ FP than it is about haskell itself). Im still stuck though, dont know how to deal with nested expressions.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks guys.

What do you mean with filter (not . all isSpace) . groupBy (\a b -> all isDigit [a,b]) @user2407038 ? I tried to make it work, but I dont fully understand.